# AttributeError: None does not have the attribute 'print'

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

So I am practicing some unit test and I am trying to check for an output that is within a For Loop. Here is my run code

```
def main():

  for i in range(100):
    print("Argh!")
```

Pretty basic, now here is my test code.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock  # possibly "from unittest import mock" depending on version.
from RunFile import main

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        with mock.patch.object(main(), 'print') as mock_print:
            main()
        expected_calls = [mock.call('Argh!') for _ in range(100)]
        mock_print.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the error message I get back. I'm not to sure how to resolve this.
UPDATED: Here is the full trace back

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_main (__main__.TestMain)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jsalce/Documents/Testsuites/IfStatements/Testsuite.py", line 9, in test_main
    with mock.patch.object(RunFile, 'print') as mock_print:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1148, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1122, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <module 'RunFile' from      'C:\\Users\\jsalce\\Documents\\Testsuites\\IfStatements\\RunFile.py'> does not have the attribute 'print'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `main` does not explicitly return anything. Therefore it returns `None`. `None.print` does not exist

Comment: Are you getting a traceback, rather than just a one-line error message? If so, always post the traceback. Even if it looks like gibberish to you, it often contains critical information for others trying to debug your core.

Comment: Anyway, you have multiple problems here. First, you're trying to patch `main()`—that is, call `main` and patch whatever value it returns—rather than `main`. Second, even if you _did_ patch `main`, that wouldn't do any good, because `main` doesn't have anything named `print` for you to patch; it's calling the builtin function, not an attribute. So, you don't want to replace `main.print`, you want to replace `print` as a local, global, or builtin. The easiest way to do that is by mocking the module—`Runfile.print` will be a global for `main`, and will override the builtin.

Comment: I posted the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, for `mock.patch.object`, you want to patch something that you have an easy handle on -- e.g. a module or a class.  Usually, you need to patch something that is one level above what you want to replace.  For example if you want to patch the `foo` function in module `bar`, then you need `mock.patch.object(bar, 'foo')`.

In your case, technically, `print` is a `builtin`, but you can patch it on the module where you're using it.  This will add a `RunFile.print` "method" (which is actually a mock) that you can test assertions against.  Apparently, since `print` doesn't actually exist on the module, we need to add `create=True` to tell `mock` to create `RunFile.print` since it doesn't already exist.  With that in mind, I'd re-write the unittest as:

```
import RunFile

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        with mock.patch.object(RunFile, 'print', create=True) as mock_print:
            RunFile.main()
        expected_calls = [mock.call('Argh!') for _ in range(100)]
        mock_print.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I think you might need to explain more here for him to get it. If he removed the `()` he'd be successfully patching the `main` object, but that wouldn't do any good, because he's not calling `main.print`, he's calling `print`, which is a standard name lookup (local-or-nonlocal-or-global-or-builtin); your version works because it's creating a global named `print`, which shadows the builtin named `print`, so all is well.

Comment: @abarnert -- expanded my answer a bit.  Hopefully that helps?

Comment: I posted the full trace back. The above code doesn't seem to work for me. I know how to implement the `@patch('builtins.input, return_value= "blah')` but how would I do it here?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work for me" -- Does it raise an exception?  I would have expected it to work, but I didn't actually try it out...

Comment: The traceback that I posted above is what I got back. It shoots back the same attribute error. @mgilson

Comment: @NoobCoder -- Does it work if you pass `create=True` to `mock.patch.object`?

Comment: Ahh. it did. Can you explain why? @mgilson

Comment: @NoobCoder -- I added the explanation to the second paragraph.